# i want to store size of the log file in a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-msforeachdb

what is the wrong with

`insert into #tempA(MailSize)
EXEC sp_foreachdb_dev @command = N' USE ?
SELECT   (size * 8)/1024.0 AS size_in_mb FROM

 sys.database_files WHERE

   data_space_id = 0',
 @user_only = '1' 
select * from #tempA`

i want to store size of the log file in a temp table

Comment: Perhaps there is some trouble with your `sp_foreachdb_dev`. I don't have that one so I can't really say. If you could show the code for `sp_foreachdb_dev` it would be helpful. Or you could just use `sp_msforeachdb` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerous problems:

- The procedure you want is `sp_msforeachdb`
- That procedure takes parameter `@command1`
- There is no `@user_only` parameter.

The version below works:

```
create table #tempA (
    MailSize decimal
)

insert into #tempA(MailSize) 
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb 
        @command1 = N' USE ? 
                       SELECT (size * 8)/1024.0 AS size_in_mb 
                       FROM sys.database_files 
                       WHERE data_space_id = 0'

select * from #tempA

drop table #tempA
```